# mex with MATLAB2013a Unrecognized switch: -o

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-c++, mex

I am trying to run a code which compiles some c++ codes using mex.
I have set up mex with Microsoft Visual C++ 2010.
But when I execute the line

> mex -O fconv.cc -o fconv

I get the error

```
compile
    Usage: 
        MEX [option1 ... optionN] sourcefile1 [... sourcefileN] 
            [objectfile1 ... objectfileN] [libraryfile1 ... libraryfileN] 

    Use the -help option for more information, or consult the MATLAB API Guide. 




C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2011A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Unrecognized switch: -o.
```

I have googled a lot but couldn't find anything of use. It would be great if you someone could help me out here. I have very limited knowledge of using mex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [R2013a docs for `mex`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2013a/matlab/ref/mex.html#bqgs3ta) (and [current version](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html#bqgs3ta)), there is no `-o` option, but there is `-output`:

> `-output resultname`
>       Create binary MEX-file named resultname. Automatically appends the appropriate MEX-file extension. Overrides the default MEX-file naming mechanism.

BTW, the big O option (`-O`) is on by default unless you use `-g`.

Keep in mind that `mex` is not a compiler, but a frontend to the compiler.  It has very different syntax from what you might be used to for a compiler.

Comment: Just a note: `mex` used to be a frontend to a Perl script `mex.pl` which in turn invoked the compiler. This has changed starting with R2014a, where it now invokes the compiler directly (both `mex.exe` and the builtin MATLAB function).

Comment: @Amro Are you sure? I'm running R2014b and I get the following error when using function syntax: `C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2014B\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Unrecognized switch: -outdir..`. At least looks like there still is a `MEX.PL` there.

Comment: @embert: I just tried compiling a sample MEX-file while running [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), and it did not touch the `mex.pl` file at all. I assume they left it for now for backward compatibility, in order not to break the old configuration system with the .BAT files instead of the new .XML files... In my case (R2014b on Win8), MATLAB first loads the library `mex_builtin.dll`, then `libmexcmd.dll`, finally it directly invokes the Visual Studio compiler via `cmd.exe`. No Perl scripts were ever executed...

Comment: @Amro So you're saying it's because my version is configured using a batch file? How would one switch from .BAT to .XML configuration? I guess it should do this on it's own, as its documented nowhere, but somehow it doesn't. Also strange: while [officially](http://de.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014b/index.html) not supported, R2014b still runs with VS2005. There are .BAT and .XML files in `bin/win64/mexopts/`. Maybe because there is not template for this old compiler, it simply makes use of the self configured .BAT.

Comment: @embert: I dont know, for me it happened automatically when I upgraded my MATLAB last time.. Maybe it's because VS2005 is old/unsupported thus falls back to old system. If you look inside your preferences folder (`winopen(prefdir)`), you should see see the new XML configuration files: `mex_*_win64.xml`. The old ones used to be called `mexopts.bat` and `compopts.bat`. First try to run `mex -setup`, otherwise try to create a [fresh profile](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-37KDWN/) (by setting the environment variable `MATLAB_PREFDIR` to a new location before starting MATLAB)